# How can I send a model with lists and objects inside an object? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, api, model

i hope you can please help me, i want to know how to add data to a model that has two lists and a few objects inside of another object to send it in a post api rest:

this is my model:

```
class NewClientModel {
  String taxpayer;
  String customerType;
  String rfc;
  String name;
  String fatherSurname;
  String motherSurname;
  String businessName;
  String contact;
  String phone;
  String cell;
  String taxRegime;
  Direction direction;
  List<ShippingAddressList> shippingAddressList;
  List<MailList> mailList;
  String workType;
  String howToContact;

  NewClientModel(
      {this.taxpayer,
      this.customerType,
      this.rfc,
      this.name,
      this.fatherSurname,
      this.motherSurname,
      this.businessName,
      this.contact,
      this.phone,
      this.cell,
      this.taxRegime,
      this.direction,
      this.shippingAddressList,
      this.mailList,
      this.workType,
      this.howToContact});

  NewClientModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    taxpayer = json['taxpayer'];
    customerType = json['customerType'];
    rfc = json['rfc'];
    name = json['name'];
    fatherSurname = json['fatherSurname'];
    motherSurname = json['motherSurname'];
    businessName = json['businessName'];
    contact = json['contact'];
    phone = json['phone'];
    cell = json['cell'];
    taxRegime = json['taxRegime'];
    direction = json['direction'] != null
        ? new Direction.fromJson(json['direction'])
        : null;
    if (json['shippingAddressList'] != null) {
      shippingAddressList = <ShippingAddressList>[];
      json['shippingAddressList'].forEach((v) {
        shippingAddressList.add(new ShippingAddressList.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['mailList'] != null) {
      mailList = <MailList>[];
      json['mailList'].forEach((v) {
        mailList.add(new MailList.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    workType = json['workType'];
    howToContact = json['howToContact'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['taxpayer'] = this.taxpayer;
    data['customerType'] = this.customerType;
    data['rfc'] = this.rfc;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['fatherSurname'] = this.fatherSurname;
    data['motherSurname'] = this.motherSurname;
    data['businessName'] = this.businessName;
    data['contact'] = this.contact;
    data['phone'] = this.phone;
    data['cell'] = this.cell;
    data['taxRegime'] = this.taxRegime;
    if (this.direction != null) {
      data['direction'] = this.direction.toJson();
    }
    if (this.shippingAddressList != null) {
      data['shippingAddressList'] =
          this.shippingAddressList.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.mailList != null) {
      data['mailList'] = this.mailList.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['workType'] = this.workType;
    data['howToContact'] = this.howToContact;
    return data;
  }
}

class Direction {
  int id;
  String cp;
  String stateCode;
  String noOutdoor;
  String street;
  String delegationCode;
  String noInterior;
  String city;
  String flatCode;
  String colony;
  String coordinatesCode;
  int idClient;

  Direction(
      {this.id,
      this.cp,
      this.stateCode,
      this.noOutdoor,
      this.street,
      this.delegationCode,
      this.noInterior,
      this.city,
      this.flatCode,
      this.colony,
      this.coordinatesCode,
      this.idClient});

  Direction.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    cp = json['cp'];
    stateCode = json['stateCode'];
    noOutdoor = json['noOutdoor'];
    street = json['street'];
    delegationCode = json['delegationCode'];
    noInterior = json['noInterior'];
    city = json['city'];
    flatCode = json['flatCode'];
    colony = json['colony'];
    coordinatesCode = json['coordinatesCode'];
    idClient = json['idClient'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['cp'] = this.cp;
    data['stateCode'] = this.stateCode;
    data['noOutdoor'] = this.noOutdoor;
    data['street'] = this.street;
    data['delegationCode'] = this.delegationCode;
    data['noInterior'] = this.noInterior;
    data['city'] = this.city;
    data['flatCode'] = this.flatCode;
    data['colony'] = this.colony;
    data['coordinatesCode'] = this.coordinatesCode;
    data['idClient'] = this.idClient;
    return data;
  }
}

class ShippingAddressList {
  int id;
  String street;
  String noOutdoor;
  String noInterior;
  String cp;
  String city;
  String colony;
  String stateCode;
  String delegationCode;
  String flatCode;
  String coordinatesCode;
  String uvicationName;
  int idClient;

  ShippingAddressList(
      {this.id,
      this.street,
      this.noOutdoor,
      this.noInterior,
      this.cp,
      this.city,
      this.colony,
      this.stateCode,
      this.delegationCode,
      this.flatCode,
      this.coordinatesCode,
      this.uvicationName,
      this.idClient});

  ShippingAddressList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    street = json['street'];
    noOutdoor = json['noOutdoor'];
    noInterior = json['noInterior'];
    cp = json['cp'];
    city = json['city'];
    colony = json['colony'];
    stateCode = json['stateCode'];
    delegationCode = json['delegationCode'];
    flatCode = json['flatCode'];
    coordinatesCode = json['coordinatesCode'];
    uvicationName = json['uvicationName'];
    idClient = json['idClient'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['street'] = this.street;
    data['noOutdoor'] = this.noOutdoor;
    data['noInterior'] = this.noInterior;
    data['cp'] = this.cp;
    data['city'] = this.city;
    data['colony'] = this.colony;
    data['stateCode'] = this.stateCode;
    data['delegationCode'] = this.delegationCode;
    data['flatCode'] = this.flatCode;
    data['coordinatesCode'] = this.coordinatesCode;
    data['uvicationName'] = this.uvicationName;
    data['idClient'] = this.idClient;
    return data;
  }
}

class MailList {
  int id;
  String mail;
  int idClient;

  MailList({this.id, this.mail, this.idClient});

  MailList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    mail = json['mail'];
    idClient = json['idClient'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['mail'] = this.mail;
    data['idClient'] = this.idClient;
    return data;
  }
}
```

This is the way I was getting the data inside the model:

[method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb5v4.png)

I wonder how can i send it to the method and then to the endpoint i have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For making API request you can use dio library

```
// initilise your model
final newClientModel = NewClientModel(...);

// import DIO dependency
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

/// pass it to post method
Response response = await Dio().post('YOUR_URL',
  options: Options(headers: {
    HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
  }),
  data: jsonEncode(newClientModel.toJson()),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i've seen many examples to help me understand how to make the complete Dio library but finally got it!